# Visual Studio 2017 VB.NET error BC30451: 'variable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm pulling my hair out over this one:
I recently upgraded a project solution to VS 2017. At first all went well, then 'something happened'. I have no idea what happened but now I cannot declare variables in local routines anymore.

For example, I have some variables in a button click event. I try and add 'Dim testvar as string ="XXXX" and all seems well, no compile or syntax errors but if I break at the line of code below the Dim statement and then try and do a Quickwatch on the variable it displays an error, saying:
'error BC30451: 'testvar' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

Nothing I do to the project gets rid of this error - except if I declare it at the top under the Public Class statement i.e. raise its scope to form level instead of at the click event routine level.

What have I done?

And why is VS2017 so fragile?

It honestly seems to me that sometimes you've only got to look at it funny and it breaks!

Comment: For the record, millions of people use VS the world over with little to no problems. I've never had any major problems. If you can create such complex software with so few bugs, you'll be doing very well. That doesn't mean that bugs aren't there and, if one person experiences a lot, it may be due to a corrupt installation. In that case, I'd try a repair as a first option.

Comment: In your specific case, do you see the same issue in any other projects? It sounds like there is some disconnect between the debugger and the project, which could be due to corruption of a file somewhere. It may be worthwhile deleting all the non-essential files that VS can regenerate and see whether that makes a difference. Failing any other solution, it might be worth creating a new project in the same solution and then dragging project items from the old to the new in the Solution Explorer and, if the behaviour doesn't copy, deleting the old project.

Comment: Let this be your motivation to start using source control, so that you can always revert to an older good state if disaster strikes. You can create a free Azure DevOps account and everything you need is built into VS. It provides more benefits for teams but the history and off-site backup is still a boon for individuals. There are other options besides DevOps too, e.g. Github.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers. I didn't have this problem in VS2012, onl since moving to 2017. FYI I have worked around the problem for now because I noticed that if I actually used the variable the problem went away and the variable's contents were displayed. It's only if I dim the variable and assign it a value and then not use it anywhere (not that I'd do that of course!) that the problem arises. I see it all over the place now, even in the Watch window if the variable in question goes out of scope. Don't know what it;s all about but I can at least work with it now.

Comment: As for VS 2017's fragility sorry but it is fragile. If I give someone a PHP website, 99% of the time it will all run just fine. I gave a colleague a copy of this solution however and when he did eventually get it to open he couldn't even put a breakpoint in the code to see what I was going on about. There's hidden files, fixes that involve deleting whole folders (obj for example) and all sorts of weird things to watch out for. I spend more time wrestling with the IDE and the language than getting work done. Why for example is 'MessageBox' such a mess? MsgBox worked fine!

Comment: And re: MessageBox v MsgBox, why are the constants for styling and buttons buried so deep as in: Microsoft.VisualBasic etc.? Why do I have to CType them to get them to work? Why also is 'MsgBox' even presented as an option but then Option Strict jumps on it and tells you effectively that you can't use it. Why is it there then? Then there's horrid little bugs which have been there years, like double-clicking a button to go to the Click event code, only to find it creates an empty event of a different sort, like TextChanged or whatever? The seconds of time used to delete these builds up!

Answer (score 0):

So anyway, as I mentioned I got round this issue by actually using the variable in question and the error goes away. I suspect the error it displays is trying to tell me that it hasn't been used yet but it's a baffling error when you just need to get work done.
Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Please consider [accepting your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).